# Cannot login to Ubuntu 16.04 after updating

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, login

I use `Ubuntu 16.04` and installed NVIDIA driver. Today after doing automatically `proposed update`, I cannot login to `Ubuntu`. I tried these ways:

- deleting `NVIDIA` or deleting `/home/*/.Xauthority` files ([Can't login to Ubuntu 16.04 after upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/q/759871))
- Uninstalling `ubuntu-desktop` and installing `xubuntu-desktop`(https://superuser.com/q/1106510)

But no one could help me. I think problem is caused by disabling some things during installing NVIDIA. How I can solve my problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Press `CTRL+ALT+F2` and log in. Next purge all of the installed nvidia-drivers:

```
sudo apt purge nvidia-*
```

Install proprietary Nvidia driver again. First of all check which version proprietary driver is suitable for you, run in terminal:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

You'll see something like this:

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00000A65sv00001043sd00008354bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GT218 [GeForce 210]
driver   : nvidia-340 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

Pay your attention to the line with `distro non-free recommended` - there is exact name of package you may install - in the example above it's `nvidia-340`. Install the detected driver (change driver version `3XX` in the command below to your detected version):

```
sudo apt install nvidia-3XX
```

Reboot computer:

```
sudo reboot
```

Check Nvidia proprietary driver in use, run in terminal:

```
nvidia-smi
```

**Remark.** Another way to install recommended proprietary drivers is command:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```