# How can I remove the drivers installed with the NVIDIA installer?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, uninstall

I installed the GPU drivers for my NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070 Ti graphics adapter using the installer file from NVIDIA, but I want to remove them and switch to the drivers being provided by the Ubuntu repositories. How can I completely remove the currently installed official (original) NVIDIA drivers?

Comment: Did you keep the pieces of the "installer from NVIDIA"? Surely some file has install/uninstall instructions. If you didn't keep the pieces, you can download it again.

Comment: @waltinator I've run `sudo apt purge nvidia-*`, then installed the 396 ppa and it seems to have worked

Comment: @TomHarris I don't think that `apt purge` can remove the original NVIDIA drivers completely, simply because they were not installed via `apt` command ... possibly you may experience issues later on. :)

Comment: @cl-netbox you bet. Its totally screwed. I think I might have to reinstall

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Completely removing old Nvidia drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054242/completely-removing-old-nvidia-drivers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Execute `sudo nvidia-installer --uninstall`, this command completely removes the NVIDIA drivers. Do not forget to remove configuration files, such like `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and those ones which blacklist the `nouveau` drivers, usually located in the `/etc/modprobe.d` folder. Depending on your specific setup, other configurations may need to be reverted too. Reboot the system afterwards.

```
$ nvidia-installer --advanced-options
...
  --uninstall
      Uninstall the currently installed NVIDIA driver.
...
```

Comment: `nvidia-installer` not found

Comment: @TomHarris Because you messed up the system by not correctly uninstalling the original NVIDIA drivers **before** you have installed the drivers from the Ubuntu repositories. The command is part of the original NVIDIA drivers installation, I have them installed and use it when new NVIDIA drivers get released. :)

Comment: I was really in a hurry to get this thing working at the time. I have no doubt it's a correct answer. I have just reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04 and used the nvidia-390 driver from the Software & Updates menu. Thanks for your help anyway 